# Laravel Livewire Multiple File Upload - issue foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to upload multiple files.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Tour;

use App\Models\Tour;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Services\SlugService;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use Livewire\Component;


class Create extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;


    public $title;
    public $slug;
    public $price;
    public $description;
    public $included;
    public $excluded;
    public $highlight;  
    public $thumbnail;
    public $images = [];

    protected $rules = [
        'title' => 'required|max:100',
        'slug' => 'required|max:100',
        'price' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'included' => '',
        'excluded' => '',
        'highlight' => '',
        'thumbnail' => 'nullable|image|max:2048',
        'images.*' => 'image'
    ];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.tour.create');
    }

    public function updatedTitle()
    {
        $this->slug = SlugService::createSlug(Tour::class, 'slug', $this->title);
    }

    public function storeTour()
    {
        $this->validate();

        $filename = $this->thumbnail->store('/','tours');

        foreach ($this->images as $key => $image) {
            $this->images[$key] = $image->store('/' , 'tours');
        }
    
        $this->images = json_encode($this->images);

        Tour::create([
            'thumbnail' => $filename,
            'images' => $this->images,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'price' => $this->price,
            'included' => $this->included,
            'excluded' => $this->excluded,
            'highlight' => $this->highlight
        ]);
        session()->flash('success', 'Tour has been successfully Saved.');

    }
}
```

and my component looks like

```
            <x-input.group for="Image" label="Image Gallery" :error="$errors->first('images.*')">
                <x-input.file-upload wire:model="images" type="file" id="images" class="w-52 h-52 p-4"
                multiple />
                @if($images)
                    @foreach ($images as $image)
                        <img src="{{ $image->temporaryUrl() }}" class="w-52 p-4">
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            </x-input.group>
```

But I want to store on database. It uploads succesfully but I have got an annoying error.

ErrorException
foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given

I tried lots of solutions but still doesnt understand whats the error and looks lots of different examples. Same code. They dont get any error. I dont understand why im getting this error.

Comment: `$this->images = json_encode($this->images);` that makes it a string. Storing JSON encoded data in a database sounds like a bad design, and you should be storing it in a separate table.

Comment: @Qirel What is proper design for to do that ? if it is separate table. You think encoded another table still bad design ? If you let me know proper way to do that. I will be glad.

Comment: You should have a `TourImages` model, that holds all the images related to that Tour. Storing JSON or comma-separated data in a table can often be a sign of a bad table-structure design. Makes it harder to modify and update the data when its not properly stored.

Comment: @Qirel Thank you for your help.